# Error loading image url with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

What I'm trying to do is to display images using an image url and I'm using the glide library to load these images however whenever I try to run the application, the images are unable to show or wont load on the activity. I'm able to see the text being displayed but not the images

This is the Error I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load on a null Context
11-11 03:23:01.713 5428-5428/? W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:84)
11-11 03:23:01.713 5428-5428/? W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:629)
```

This is the code

```
 public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <SampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<SampleModel> list;
    private Context mContext = null;

    public SampleAdapter(List<SampleModel> sampleModelList) {
        this.list = sampleModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public SampleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WatchlistAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       String image = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/9HE9xiNMEFJnCzndlkWD7oPfAOx.jpg";

        try{
               final SampleModel sample = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

               if(sample != null) {
              holder.title.setText(sample.getTitle());
              Glide.with(mContext).load(image)
                   .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                   .dontAnimate()
                   .fitCenter()
                   .crossFade()
                   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                   .into(holder.cover);
            } else {
              Glide.clear(holder.cover);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return (list != null? list.size():0);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView title;
        public ImageView cover;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            cover= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverImage);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Check your mContext. Probably you didn't initialize the context properly and hence it's null which is causing the problem.

Comment: @oathkeeper I've updated my code. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this :

```
public SampleAdapter(List<SampleModel> sampleModelList, Context context) {
    this.list = sampleModelList;
    mContext = context ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before this :

```
 Glide.with(mContext).load(image)
               .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
               .dontAnimate()
               .fitCenter()
               .crossFade()
               .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
               .into(holder.cover);
```

mContext is not assigned any Context value. It still has the value you have initialised with (that is null). So, you need to assign its value as suggested by @Kapta and pass the context as parameter in the SampleAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually as long as your ImageView `holder.cover` is not `null`, you may just conveniently use `holder.cover.getContext()` for that.